# Spring Boot - Rabbit Custom ConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

Are there any public utility methods available in Spring AMQP/Rabbit to create a custom Rabbit Connection Factory. As of now, I am using the following code

```
@Bean(name = "rp1")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.custom")
    public RabbitProperties rp1() {
        return new RabbitProperties();
    }

   
    public ConnectionFactory cf1(
            @Qualifier("rp1") RabbitProperties rp1) {

        final CachingConnectionFactory cf1 = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(rp1.getHost());
       //remaing code left off 
    }
    
    
    @Bean(name = "rp2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.custom1")
    public RabbitProperties rp2() {
        return new RabbitProperties();
    }
    
    public ConnectionFactory cf2(
            @Qualifier("rp2") RabbitProperties rp2) {

        final CachingConnectionFactory cf2 = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(rp2.getHost());
       //remaing code left off 
    }
```

In application.properties, the following values are passed

Sample properties

1. app.custom.host=localhost app.custom.port=5372
2. app.custom1.host=localhost1 app.custom1.port=5373

Is there a better way to do this like, passing a custom RabbitProperties and getting a Connection Factory back by setting all the properties? Basically something similar to rabbitConnectionFactory bean in RabbitAutoConfiguration RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator class. I need st support multiple rabbit clusters in my application. Hence cannot use the Autoconfiguration, since it supports only 1 cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum what we can suggest is a `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean`. It is not recommended to use out-of-the-box `@ConfigurationProperties` in the target projects. They are mostly internal for Spring Boot and are subject for often changes.

You definitely can borrow a configuration idea from the mentioned auto-configuration and build your own `CachingConnectionFactory` object.

**UPDATE**

According to your it sounds like you really can extract a common method to be called with a specific properties instance:

```
@Bean(name = "rp1")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.custom")
public RabbitProperties rp1() {
    return new RabbitProperties();
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory cf1(
        @Qualifier("rp1") RabbitProperties rp1) {

    return createConnectionFactoryByProperties(rp1);

}


@Bean(name = "rp2")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.custom1")
public RabbitProperties rp2() {
    return new RabbitProperties();
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory cf2(
        @Qualifier("rp2") RabbitProperties rp2) {

         return createConnectionFactoryByProperties(rp2);
}

private CachingConnectionFactory createConnectionFactoryByProperties(RabbitProperties rp) {
    final CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(rp.getHost());
   //remaing code left off 
}
```

Comment: Currently I am using a custom ConfigurationProperties to create RabbitProperties. 
```
@Bean(name = "rp1")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.custom")
    public RabbitProperties rp1() {
        return new RabbitProperties();
    }

   
    public ConnectionFactory customConnectionFactory(
            @Qualifier("rp1") RabbitProperties rp1) {

        final CachingConnectionFactory cf1 = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(rp1.getHost());
       //remaing code left off 
    }
'''
Do you see any issues?

Comment: And what is the point to use `RabbitProperties` since you already have your own?

Comment: Currently I am using a custom ConfigurationProperties to create RabbitProperties. ``` @Bean(name = "rp1") @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.custom") public RabbitProperties rp1() { return new RabbitProperties(); } public ConnectionFactory customConnectionFactory( @Qualifier("rp1") RabbitProperties rp1) { final CachingConnectionFactory cf1 = new CachingConnectionFactory(); connectionFactory.setHost(rp1.getHost()); //remaing code left off } ''' Do you see any issues?

Comment: and different properties for borkers are passed through env properties like app.custom.host, app.custom1.host, app.custom2.host etc and custom Rabbitproperties beans are defined for each of these prefixes

Comment: That would be great if you added that code into the question: it is just not readable from the comments... If that works for you, then you are good to go. As I said: without Spring Boot you even have to support your own mechanism to read the properties.

Comment: I have added the code into the question..Yes, It is working fine for me..Also, my application is  Spring boot application..

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.